# How do I create/find .cpg files after creating a shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I've been asked to map an area of land using QGIS, so I created a new vector layer polygon and saved it to my PC without problems.

They've asked for the following files: .shp, .shx, .dbf, .prj and .cpg.

When I go to the folder containing my saved polygon files, all files except .cpg are there.

How do I create a .cpg file for my polygon?

Comment: .cpg isn't a required extension for your file. From http://gisgeography.com/arcgis-shapefile-files-types-extensions/  : ".cpg: These are optional plain text files that describes the encoding applied to create the Shapefile. If your shapefile doesn’t have a cpg file, then it has the system default encoding."

Comment: Thanks MaryBeth. They've said they definitely need a .cpg file but I'll try and explain to them what you said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The .cpg file is optional.

It is used to specify the code page (only for .dbf) for identifying the character encoding to be used (for example to encode utf-8).

It should not be a problem for the one who gets the shapefile to open it without .cpg-file

For further information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

But if you really need that file. just open a texteditor and write "**UTF-8**" into the first line and save it as "shapefilename.cpg"

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I'll try your text editor suggestion. What does UTF-8 mean?

Comment: UTF-8 is a character encoding capable of encoding all possible Unicode code points. It encodes the text so all possible letters are written correctly and not like hieroglyphics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: To decide if *you really need that file*, check if the attributes contain wrong representations of characters. E.g. "KreisbÃ¶gen" instead of "Kreisbögen" etc. In QGIS you can also go to "Layer Properties -> Source -> Data Source Encoding" to quickly check some different encodings that are correct for the data you have.

Answer (score 0):

A quick update to the answer. You may find that your data haven't been saved in *UTF-8*. You will need to use a different code in the cpg file.

For example, Latin-9 requires the code *ISO 88591* instead. Just that, one small line of text at the top of a text file. The encoding of this text file (the cpg file) can be UTF-8 or whatever the OS prefers.

QGIS doesn't need the cpg file and works out for itself what the dbf file's encoding is.

Answer (score -3):

In the 'Save As' window select 'UTF-8'as Encoding.